# How do you show $n^3$ as a sum of terms?

Tags: summation

We know that $n^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n 2i-1$.

Is there a similar way to represent $n^3$ as: $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n ?$, where we replace the question mark with a term?

Comment: Sure--Compute $n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2-3n+1$ and deduce that $$n^3=\sum_{i=1}^n(3i^2-3i+1).$$

Comment: Note that @Did's expansion is exactly like the sum for $n^2$ mentioned in the Question since $n^2 - (n-1)^2 = 2n - 1$.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thes comments you got so far should make for a good way through for you. Alternatively (similarly), you may look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_of_polynomial_expressions) to see that

\begin{align}
S_1&=\sum_1^n i =\frac12n^2+\frac12n\\
S_2&=\sum_1^n i^2 =\frac13n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac16n\\
\end{align}
Now look at $S_2-S_1$:
\begin{align}
S_2-S_1&=\sum_1^n i^2-\sum_1^n i\\
 &=\frac13n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac16n-\frac12n^2-\frac12n\\
&=\frac13n^3-\frac13n\\
\end{align}
Therefore 
\begin{align}
3\sum_1^n i^2-3\sum_1^n i&=n^3-n\\
\end{align}
Now recall that $\sum_1^n 1=n$ hence 
\begin{align}
3\sum_1^n i^2-3\sum_1^n i&=n^3-\sum_1^n 1\\
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
3\sum_1^n i^2-3\sum_1^n i+\sum_1^n 1&=n^3\\
\sum_1^n(3 i^2-3 i+ 1)&=n^3\\
\end{align}